# SIGILL while compiling PHP with optimization flag

Tags: php, optimization, gcc, compilation, gdb

In my shell script, the CFLAGS reads as follows:

```
export CFLAGS="-O2 -mtune=native -march=native -pipe"
```

while I compiling PHP WITH these flags, the sapi/cli/php reports SIGILL error,
otherwise I remevoed the flag declaration, the compilation is fine.

I use gdb, however, found that it said "`Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction zend_strtod ()`"

So, what is the cause of that error ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in PHP. There's probably a better place to ask this question, maybe the Installation and Configuration forum at http://www.devnetwork.net/

Answer (score 1):

This is either a bug in PHP or in your compiler.

Try running PHP (built without these flags) under Valgrind and see what you get. Then report the bug you found.